# How do I select a random string from a list in Python?

Tags: python, random

```
add = ""

addmovie = raw_input("Type 'a' to add a title, 'b' to pick a movie or '/' to quit: ")
while addmovie == 'a' or addmovie == '/' or addmovie == 'b':
    if addmovie == 'a':
    add = list(add) + list(raw_input("Enter movie name: "))
    elif addmovie == '/':
        print 'Goodbye.'
        sys.exit()
    elif addmovie == 'b':
        break
    addmovie = raw_input("Type 'a' to add a title, 'b' to pick a movie or '/' to quit: ")

# Define Movie_list and random choice

Movie_list = list(add) #+ movie_list

random_movie = random.choice(Movie_list)

print random_movie
```

movie_list was defined previously

If it's possible with only while loops and if/elif/else that'd be helpful. I've only learned up to this material.

Comment: Hopefully it's showing now.

Comment: It is not possible without a random generator. So you probably could use [`random#randrange()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange) or [implement your own](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators). Once you have your random generator, it only remains to select that element.

Answer (score 1):

So first you may want to check what pythons list() function does to strings.
[python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list)

Simply put list("foo") will create the list ['f', 'o', 'o']. Which I guess may not be what you expect the function to do :)

You are storing all your movies in a string, which may be okay but I'd suggest to use a simple array (especially if you want to use the data later again, like picking a random item).

So instead of concatenating all the input movie names:

```
add = list(add) + list(raw_input("Enter movie name: "))
```

You could simply append them into an array:

```
movies.append(raw_input("Enter movie name: "))
```

Then if you use random.choice(movies) a pseudorandom item from that array will be returned.

So your code may look like this:

```
import sys, random

# Movie_List is now here
movies = []

addmovie = raw_input("Type 'a' to add a title, 'b' to pick a movie or '/' to quit: ")
 while addmovie == 'a' or addmovie == '/' or addmovie == 'b':
    if addmovie == 'a':
        movies.append(raw_input("Enter movie name: "))
    elif addmovie == '/':
        print 'Goodbye.'
        sys.exit()
    elif addmovie == 'b':
        break
    addmovie = raw_input("Type 'a' to add a title, 'b' to pick a movie or '/' to quit: ")

# random choice
random_movie = random.choice(movies)
print random_movie
```